# Using MKMapView and Core Data to index and display locations?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, mkmapview

I'm going to be building a custom map application that has a custom, pre-determined list of locations (I want to have this list stored inside the app itself, so the user doesn't have to load it for use). Basically, I'm going for sort of a "closed" maps app; one that has a rather large searchable array of locations, and when a user finds the one they want, it loads an annotation onto the mapview and displays the location.

Before I begin on this endeavor, I wanted to get some feedback and see if my chosen tools would be the best for the job at hand. So, would MKMapView and Core Data be the simplest and most efficient way to implement this idea? I'm definitely open to suggestions, ideas, etc, and thanks in advance for your feedback and thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a predefined set of locations, then definitely MKMapView with coredata/sqlite is the best option.